# Can I avoid redundantly casting a Throwable when using catching(...).either?

Tags: exception, scala

I'm using `util.control.Exception.catching` to convert internal exceptions into an exception type specific to my library:

```
import util.control.Exception._

abstract class MyException extends Exception

case class ErrorOccurredDuringFoo(e : Exception) extends MyException

def foo : Foo = {
    catching(classOf[Exception]) either { fooInternals } match {
        case Left(e) => throw ErrorOccurredDuringFoo(e)
        case Right(v) => v
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Applying the `Catch` returned by `either` doesn't return `Either[Exception,Foo]`, it returns `Either[Throwable,Foo]`. But I've already told `catching` I want it to catch only subtypes of `Exception`, not all `Throwable`s, and internally it's already matched an `Exception`.

Am I using this correctly? Is there no way I can convince `catching` to return the exception it catches as an instance of the class of exceptions I asked it to catch? Is my best bet to just add a redundant `asInstanceOf[Exception]`? I'd rather not if I can avoid it, as the `catching` instance could logically be created elsewhere, and I'd like to get a compile error if I one day change it to `catching[Throwable]` without changing `ErrorOccurredDuringFoo`, not a runtime error when the cast to `Exception` fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Catch` isn't parameterised on `Throwable`, only on the result type. The only way to downcast the Throwable type is with the mkCatcher method:

```
val c = catching[Foo](
  mkCatcher(
    (t: Throwable) => t.getClass == classOf[MyException],
    (e: MyException) => throw new ErrorOccurredDuringFoo(e)))
c(fooInternals)
```

But, `Catch` takes a `Catcher[T]` – which is really just an alias for a `PartialFunction[Throwable, T]`.

As a case statement *is a* `PartialFunction` we can use pattern matching:

```
val c: Catcher[Foo] = {
  case e: MyException => throw new ErrorOccurredDuringFoo(e)
}
catching(c)(fooInternals)
```

Comment: Thanks! That ends up much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it like this:

```
def foo : Foo = {
    catching(classOf[Exception]) either { fooInternals } match {
        case Left(e: Exception) => throw ErrorOccurredDuringFoo(e)
        case Right(v) => v
    }
}
```

It is interesting that it doesn't complain about missing cases.

Comment: That is interesting. Presumably though it ends up equivalent to a runtime downcast though, in that if `classOf[Exception]` is changed to `classOf[Throwable]` the compiler won't statically know that `case Left(e: Exception)` is wrong, and the result will be a runtime match error.